# Convert pixel to percent using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

i would like to know if there's a way to convert pixel to percent... I have a code which i get the value of full width successfully, but the only thing to keep the object in center, i must need to use percent.

Here's what i use on getting the value of width which i need to convert after to percent.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sp = $('.slide'),
        winWidth = $('#slides').width();
        console.log(winWidth);

    sp.css('width', winWidth);
});
```

Thanks for the help.

[Here's the updated fiddle link.](http://jsfiddle.net/imarkdesigns/4SwmE/4/)
*note: what i wanted here was to set the ".slide" container become fluid to make the object still in center spot. Feel free to modify my fiddle. Right now im using my given jQuery code to get the exact width of the "#slide" in percent to pixel ('.slide'). Then as of that, try to resize your browser to see the output of the slide frame. Im using SlidesJS plugin FYI.

Comment: if you post the html also it would be helpfull

Comment: percent of what? You can get the width of the body or whatever element you want, and then calculate percent that way.

Comment: `(child / parent) * 100`

Comment: Keep in mind that `.width()` will return solely the content of the element. Consider using `.outerWidth()` to include any padding and borders or `.outerWidth(true)` to also include margins.

Comment: Thanks for `true` param of `outerWidth` - [here's docs](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i figured out that "#slides" is not the correct element that i need to get the width value, since it was also part of the slides frame instead i get the value of event browser screen-size where i have to pass the value each time the browser screen was resizing.

Please check this link to see the updated fiddle.
[updated fiddle source](http://jsfiddle.net/imarkdesigns/4SwmE/6/)

Here's the code that i found useful to correct my problem.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var sp = $('#slides .slide');
  console.log(document.body.clientWidth);
  winWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
  sp.css('width', winWidth);
});
```

At the case, i can fully resize my width and auto-adjust my class element width without having my center object stuck at the same place.  :)

Answer (score 8):

```
percent = ($("#your_element").width() / $("#some_parent_id").width()) * 100
```

Where `$("#your_element")` is element you want to count width in `%`, where `$("#some_parent_id")` is element relative to which you want to count width.

Answer (score 3):

The percentage would be the actual value in pixels (acquired by `.width`) divided by the value of the width in pixels of the block (possibly acquired via `$("#slides").parent().width()`) multiplied by 100.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var sp = $('.slide'),
            winWidth = $('#slides').width(),
        wWidth = $(window).width();
        sp.width(((winWidth / wWidth) * 100)+'%');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simple formula to calculate pixel to percent

for jquery users

```
var w=$("#container").width();
var h=$("#container").height();
```

for javascript users

```
var w=element.getBoundingClientRect().width;
var h=element.getBoundingClientRect().height;
```

x axis percentage

```
var xPercent=Math.round(x/w*100); //x is your pixal value
```

y axis percentage

```
var yPercent=Math.round(y/h*100); // y is your pixal value
```

for drag users ,use inside move function

```
  function pixelToPercent(x,y)
{
     var xPercent=Math.round(x/w*100); //x is your pixal value
     var yPercent=Math.round(y/h*100); // y is your pixal value 

return {
xPercent,
yPercent}
 
 }
```